# React useState hook not fucntioning properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

EDIT:

By `console.log`ing outside the async function, I can view the data. I am also trying to pass this data through a `Redirect`. I skipped a lot of part initially, so here is the full function:

```
const SearchForm = () => {
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('')
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([])
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false)

    async function fetchData() {
        const { data } = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/search/', {keyword});
        setFetchedData(data);
    }

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetchData();
        setRedirect(true);
    }

    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/search', fetchedData }} />
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
                <div className='input-field'>
                <input placeholder="Search whatever you wish" 
                    type="text"
                    value={keyword}
                    onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
                />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The fetchedData is not being passed through the Redirect. When I check, its just an empty array (and that is what the initial value was).

Comment: If you want to check fetched data, just `console.log(data)` will be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calling an async function you should use `await`. So add an IIFE for the async part within the submit handler.

```
const SearchForm = () => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('')
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([])
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false)

  const handleInputChange = ({ target: { value }}) => {
    setKeyword(value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    ;(async => {
      const { data } = await axios.post(`http...`, { keyword })
      setFetchedData(data)
    })()
  }

  if (redirect) {
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/search', fetchedData }} />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input onChange={handleInputChange} />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What changes you've made? I change in here if necessary, so the answer will not mislead others. Or just click edit and propose change in my code.

Comment: It should have been a post call

Answer (score 1):

This `setFetchedData()` is an asynchronous process. Try using with a callback to get the right result:

```
setFetchedData(data, () => {
  console.log(fetchedData)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  const { useState } = React
  const App = () => {
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('Change in a sec...');
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setKeyword("Hello, changed!", () => {
        console.log(keyword);
      });
    }, 1000);
    return (
      <div>
        {keyword}
      </div>
    );
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

setstate in async operation you can find your updated state like this

```
const SearchForm = () => {
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('')
    const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([])

    async function fetchData() {
        const { data } = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/search/', { keyword });
        setFetchedData(data);
    }
    console.log(fetchedData)

    if (redirect) {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/search', data: { fetchedData } }} />
    }

    return (
            )
```

in your search component console like this :
this.props.location.data

Comment: `await` will not work without an `async` wrapper I guess.

Comment: yes i removed bymistakely. Thanks Anyway ! @gazdagergo

Comment: Yes through console.log() I can view the data like that. But I am trying to pass that data through a `Redirect` from `react-router-dom` as well. Over there, the value of the data is empty. Please check the edit

Comment: haha it seems like you've answered my previous question as well :P so you will hopefully understand this better

Comment: yup !! so please consider this as marked . happy to have help :)

Comment: The problem isn't solved yet. The fetchedData is not being passed through the Redirect

Comment: ans is edited please check .. if you still have any doubt feel free to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
function fetchData() {
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/search/', {keyword}).then(data=>{
    setFetchedData(data);
    console.log(fetchedData)
});
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Oh, you changed sync to async.

Comment: I have removed the await and asyc keywords and added the code in then() block